# Is there a way to collapse repeating column values to occurring once in python dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to create a data frame from an original dataset using groupby() method. I want the new data frame to have id, type, code, sum.

existing dataframe - 'df':

```
     type code  sum
id                 
AAA     1  abc    2
AAA     1  ses    4
AAA     1  abc    3
AAA     1  reg    5
AAA     1  ses    1
BBB     2  abc    3
BBB     1  ses    3
BBB     2  reg    2
```

I want to convert this table to another dataframe that looks like this:

```
        type  sum
code id          
AAA  1   abc    5
     1   reg    5
     1   ses    5
BBB  1   ses    3
     2   abc    3
     2   reg    2
```

I tried this code:

```
df_new= df.groupby(['id', 'type'], as_index = False)['sum'].sum()
```

but my output was:

```
 id       type        sum
  1        abc          5
  1        ses          5
  1        reg          5
  1        ses          3
  2        abc          3
  2        reg          2
```

Is there anyway to convert the existing df to the one I am trying to convert?

Comment: add your dataframe as : ```df = pd.DataFrame({'id': ['AAA', 'AAA', 'AAA', 'AAA', 'AAA', 'BBB', 'BBB', 'BBB'],
        'type': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2],
        'code': ['abc', 'ses', 'abc', 'reg', 'ses', 'abc', 'ses', 'reg'],
        'sum': [2, 4, 3, 5, 1, 3, 3, 2]})```

Similarly your output as well for better understanding the data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming this input, in which you have "code" as index and a column named "code":

```
      id type code  sum
code                   
AAA    1  abc  aaa    2
AAA    1  ses  aaa    4
AAA    1  abc  aaa    3
AAA    1  reg  aaa    5
AAA    1  ses  aaa    1
BBB    2  abc  bbb    3
BBB    1  ses  bbb    3
BBB    2  reg  bbb    2
```

You need to first [`drop`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) the "code" column as it has the same name as the index. Then you can [`groupby.sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.sum.html) making sure to add the index "code" as grouper:

```
df_new = (df.drop(columns='code')
            .groupby(['code', 'id', 'type']).sum()
            .reset_index('type')
         )
```

Output:

```
        type  sum
code id          
AAA  1   abc    5
     1   reg    5
     1   ses    5
BBB  1   ses    3
     2   abc    3
     2   reg    2
```

Reproducible input:

```
df = (pd.DataFrame({'index': ['AAA', 'AAA', 'AAA', 'AAA', 'AAA', 'BBB', 'BBB', 'BBB'],
                    'id': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2],
                    'type': ['abc', 'ses', 'abc', 'reg', 'ses', 'abc', 'ses', 'reg'],
                    'code': ['aaa', 'aaa', 'aaa', 'aaa', 'aaa', 'bbb', 'bbb', 'bbb'],
                    'sum': [2, 4, 3, 5, 1, 3, 3, 2]})
       .set_index('index').rename_axis('code')
     )
```

Alternatively, if you don't want to `drop` "code", you could pass the index as grouper rather than using its name:

```
df_new = (df.groupby([df.index, 'id', 'type'])
            .agg({'code': 'first', 'sum': 'sum'})
            .reset_index('type')
         )
```

Output:

```
        type code  sum
code id               
AAA  1   abc  aaa    5
     1   reg  aaa    5
     1   ses  aaa    5
BBB  1   ses  bbb    3
     2   abc  bbb    3
     2   reg  bbb    2
```