# Is there a way to create and rearrange a dataframe in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to create a data frame from an original dataset using `groupby()` method. I want the new data frame to have id, type, code, sum.

existing dataframe - 'df':

| code | id | type | code | sum |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AAA | 1 | abc | AAA | 2 |
|  | 1 | ses | AAA | 4 |
|  | 1 | abc | AAA | 3 |
|  | 1 | reg | AAA | 5 |
|  | 1 | ses | AAA | 1 |
| BBB | 2 | abc | BBB | 2 |
|  | 1 | ses | BBB | 3 |
|  | 2 | reg | BBB | 2 |
|  | 2 | abc | BBB | 1 |

I want to convert this table into another dataframe that will look like this:

| code | id | type | Sum |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AAA | 1 | abc | 5 |
|  |  | ses | 5 |
|  |  | reg | 5 |
| BBB |  | ses | 3 |
|  | 2 | abc | 3 |
|  |  | reg | 2 |

I tried this code:

```
df_new= df.groupby(['id', 'type'], as_index = False)['sum'].sum()
```

but my output was:

| id | type | Sum |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | abc | 5 |
| 1 | ses | 6 |
| 1 | reg | 5 |
| 1 | ses | 3 |
| 2 | abc | 3 |
| 2 | reg | 2 |

Is there any way to convert the existing df to the one I am trying to convert?

Comment: Why did you delete you previous question? Please provide a reproducible object as input, not a table that is ambiguous.

Comment: @mozway, I am new to stack overflow. I am not sure how to add a table in the description.

Comment: @jessu we don't want a table, we want [**code** to instantiate the DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20109391/16343464)

Comment: I'd also recommend to delete this question and undelete [your other one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77314028/16343464) since I already had given you an answer (you can then comment on this answer if this doesn't work as you want and [edit it](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77314028/edit) to add the reproducible input)

Comment: I tried this`df.groupby(['id','type', 'code' ], as_index = False)['sum'].sum()` but the output was similar to what I don't want.

Comment: Please understand that we cannot answer until you give a reproducible example **as code**, your input is too ambiguous. We **need** the output of `df.to_dict('tight')`, please [edit] the question.

Comment: @mozway, thank you for your guidance. Ill take a look at it :)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I'm closing this one since the original question was undeleted and seemed to be solved